# Tampermonkey GM.xmlHttpRequest is not a function

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I'm seriously struggling trying to resolve an issue with my script. Whatever I try and do GM.xmlHttpRequest throws error "is not a function".

The rest of my code works fine.

This is an abridged version of my code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         FUT20 Autobuyer Menu
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.6
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       Rastor
// @match        https://www.easports.com/uk/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/*
// @match        https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/*
// @grant        GM.xmlHttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

        try {
            GM.xmlHttpRequest({
              method: "GET",
              url: "http://www.example.com/",
              onload: function(response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
              }
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
```

Comment: The code is missing `// ==UserScript==` at the beginning.

Comment: It is but unfortunately that's just how it's copied in. Everything else is working.

Comment: I've edited the post above to show what the code actually looks like. I had missed that line in the post above. When it appears in the actual code it still doesn't work.

Comment: Since the posted code works for me I guess there's a bug in your version of Tampermonkey or browser or there's a typo in your actual code.

Answer (score 6):

In Tampermonkey it is `GM_xmlhttpRequest` (underscore not dot) as the privilege and function name!

Comment: Not true. GM_xmlHttpRequest is not defined and GM.xmlHttpRequest is not a function.

Comment: Did you `// @grant GM_xmlhttpRequest`? Also read the Tampermonkey documentation: https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_xmlhttpRequest

Comment: I'm now using `GM.xmlHttpRequest` which I also had to `@grant` and it's working in Tampermonkey. It's not `GM_xmlHttpRequest`. Don't know why the documentation is wrong.

Comment: @dtrunk it's `GM_xmlhttpRequest` with a small h. Unfortunately the original answer has a capital H (and I can't change it because the edit queue is full atm).

Comment: `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, `GM_xmlHttpRequest`, `GM.xmlhttpRequest`, `GM.xmlHttpRequest`, so confusing hahaha. Actually what the difference between `GM_xmlhttpRequest` and `GM.xmlHttpRequest`?? I've tried both of the two but both seems to be working fine to me.

Comment: in my case, I forgot to remove the default line `// @grant        none`