# What's a reliable method to extract external Youtube Channel ID with Tampermonkey / Greasemonkey?

Tags: html, youtube, console, tampermonkey

I have written a tampermonkey script, but I am not sure that it actually works properly:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name YouTube Channel ID Extractor
// @namespace https://example.com/
// @version 0.1
// @description Extracts the external channel ID and alternate usernames of a YouTube channel and logs them to console
// @author sharmanhall
// @match https://www.youtube.com/*
// @grant none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Find the canonical link tag and extract the channel ID from its href attribute
    const canonicalLink = document.querySelector('link[rel="canonical"]');
    const channelID = canonicalLink ? canonicalLink.href.split('/').pop() : null;

    // Find the alternate link tags and extract the usernames from their href attributes
    const alternateLinks = document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="alternate"]');
    const usernames = Array.from(alternateLinks)
        .filter(link => link.href.includes('@'))
        .map(link => link.href.split('/').pop());

    // Log the extracted values to console
    if (channelID && usernames.length === 2) {
        console.log('External Channel ID:', channelID);
        console.log('Alternate Username #1:', usernames[0]);
        console.log('Alternate Username #2:', usernames[1]);
    } else {
        console.error('Error: Could not extract all required values.');
    }
})();
```

Because I think there may be some other edge cases I have not thought of. It seems to work on some profiles but not all of them. **So what's the best way to extract the external channel ID of a youtube channel?**

The script looks for this code in the page source:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/[CHANNEL_ID]">
<link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href="https://m.youtube.com/@[USERNAME]">
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="https://m.youtube.com/@[USERNAME]">
```

And prints it nicely to console for me like so:

```
External Channel ID: CHANNEL_ID
Alternate Username #1: @[USERNAME]
Alternate Username #2: @D[USERNAME]
```

Thanks for any help!

I tried the script above, and it works on some channels, not all of them. I am seeking a better solution to programmatically extract YouTube channel ID.

UPDATE:

I wrote an API script, but it doesn't seem to extract properly either :(

```js
    // ==UserScript==
    // @name         YouTube Channel ID Extractor (API v2)
    // @namespace    https://www.example.com/
    // @version      1
    // @description  Extracts the external channel ID of a YouTube channel and logs it to console
    // @author sharmanhall
    // @match        https://www.youtube.com/*
    // @grant        GM_xmlhttpRequest
    // ==/UserScript==
    
    (function() {
        'use strict';
    
        // Get the current page's URL
        const url = window.location.href;
    
        // Check if the URL is a YouTube username URL
        const match = url.match(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?youtube\.com\/@([^/?]+)/i);
        if (match) {
            const username = match[3];
            console.log('%cYoutube Username:', 'font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;', username);
    
            // Call the YouTube Data API to search for the channel by username
            GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                method: 'GET',
                url: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=${username}&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`,
                onload: function(response) {
                    const data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                    if (data.items && data.items.length === 1) {
                        const externalChannelID = data.items[0].id;
                        console.log('%cExternal Channel ID:', 'font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;', externalChannelID);
                    } else {
                        console.error('%cError: Could not extract external channel ID.', 'font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;');
                    }
                },
                onerror: function(response) {
                    console.error('%cError: Could not call YouTube Data API.', 'font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;');
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.error('%cError: Not a YouTube username URL.', 'font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;');
        }
    })();
```

I gets the username, but then I get "Error: Could not extract external channel ID." logged to console everytime.

Comment: Check the length of `data.items` = probably you're getting more than 1 or just plain zero results, hence, this condition: `if (data.items && data.items.length === 1)` is not met.

Comment: I have suspicion about ```GM_xmlhttpRequest```,  please try with ```GM.xmlhttpRequest``` (don't forget the proper @grant). source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62260162/tampermonkey-gm-xmlhttprequest-is-not-a-function If not working, please provide the detailed response content.